# How to dynamically and efficiently pull information from database (notifications) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, notifications

I am working in a Rails application and below is the scenario requiring a solution.

I'm doing some time consuming processes in the background using `Sidekiq` and saves the related information in the database. Now when each of the process gets completed, we would like to show `notifications` in a separate area saying that the `process has been completed`.

So, the notifications area really need to pull things from the back-end (This notification area will be available in every page) and show it dynamically. So, I thought Ajax must be an option. But, I don't know how to trigger it for a particular area only. Or is there any other option by which Client can fetch dynamic content from the server efficiently without creating much traffic.

I know it would be a broad topic to say about. But any relevant info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I think a good way to go about this would be to use Streaming controller provided in the RAILS 4.Listen for changes and emit the data in json format and update the view accordingly.

Comment: how about [wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper)?

Comment: @emaillenin: Thanks for the info. Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at a perpetual connection (either using SSE's or Websockets), something Rails has started to look at with [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html)

---

**Live**

You're looking for "live" connectivity:

> "Live" functionality works by keeping a connection open
>   between your app and the server. Rails is an HTTP request-based
>   framework, meaning it only sends responses to requests. The way to
>   *send* live data is to keep the response open (using a perpetual connection), which allows you to send updated data to your page on its
>   own timescale

The way to do this is to use a front-end method to keep the connection "live", and a back-end stack to serve the updates. The front-end will need either [SSE's](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) or a [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which you'll connect with use of JS

The SEE's and websockets basically give you access to the server out of the scope of "normal" requests (they use `text/event-stream` content  / mime type)

---

**Recommendation**

We use a service called [`pusher`](http://pusher.com)

This basically creates a third-party websocket service, to which you can push updates. Once the service receives the updates, it will send it to any channels which are connected to it. You can split the channels it broadcasts to using the [pub/sub pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

I'd recommend using this service directly (they have a [Rails gem](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem)) (I'm not affiliated with them), as well as providing a super simple API

Other than that, you should look at the [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) functionality of Rails

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the answer. Anyway, please let me know if http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye (Faye) a good option for this?

Comment: Yep - Faye is just like Pusher. But bare in mind you'll need to handle the server on your end, whilst a service such as Pusher handles it for you

Comment: Thanks :) let me try the options.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested in the comment by @h0lyalg0rithm is an option to go.

However, primitive options are.

1. Use setinterval in javascript to perform a task every x seconds. Say polling.
2. Use jQuery or native ajax to poll for information to a controller/action via route and have the controller push data as JSON.
3. Use document.getElementById or jQuery to update data on the page.